# PHP Composer, command line (CLI) to add a class path to autoload PSR-4 / PSR-0 / file in composer.json

Tags: command, composer-php, command-line-interface, autoload

Does Composer have any Command from CLI to add to **composer.json** such entry?

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Monolog\\": "src/",
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

and add this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Monolog\\": "src/",
            "Vendor\\Namespace\\": "src/",
            "Vendor_Namespace_": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

and this

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/", "lib/", "Something.php"]
    }
}
```

and this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/MyLibrary/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

I looked here:
[Composer Command Line Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md)

but haven't found any dedicated command. Perhaps there is a workaround command like:

```
composer add-entry <key> <value>
```

or

```
composer set-key <key> <value>
```

but I don't know such, 
do you know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately NO.  At least in v1.8.4 and I also want this feature too.

I thought the closest command would be `config`.

```
$ composer config bin-dir bin/
$ composer config repositories.github.com '{"type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/[YOUR]/[REPO]", "//url": "https://github.com/[YOUR]/[REPO].git"}'
```

Since this will add the following in `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
},
"repositories": {
    "github.com": {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/[YOUR]/[REPO]",
        "//url": "https://github.com/[YOUR]/[REPO].git"
    }
}
```

Though, this command seems to work only for "`config`" and "`repositories`" keys.

And then I found an issue about this topic. Seems that the community won't add this feature.

> Yup I don't think we really want to offer this from CLI it's gonna be a bunch of code for very limited use as typically this is done once on package creation.
>
> - From: Issue #3398
>
>   - "[[Feature] Adding processing autoloading sections to the command line interface](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3398#issuecomment-210562767)" @ GitHub